# UNITY WheelCollider Сильное Дрожание Авто

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал модель машины в блендере, добавил её без колёс в юнити, прикрутил wheel collider'ы, и для удобства прикрутил цилиндры вместо колёс. Когда я нажимаю play машину очень сильно трясёт.

Как это исправить и почему это происходит?

Без цилиндров тоже очень сильно трясёт.

Первое фото пример тряски, второе rigidbody автомобиля.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: scale != 1, вероятно это причина бед :)

Comment: А то что у меня у всех частей машины кроме wheel collider'ов rotation около -90 по x, а у wheel collider'ов 0 как-то влияет? Просто и без цилиндров у которых scale != 1, машину колбасит. Правда, если поставить rotation x = 0, то автомобиль станет вертикальным.

Comment: А почему на колесах коллайдеры не цилинрды, а круги?